# unauthorized 401 error from Xamarin.Forms ViewModel using await client.GetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms iOS app that makes calls to an ASP.NET Web API. Here is an api call made from a Xamarin View Model:

```
private async void GetInterestList()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string token = Storage.GetKeyValue("token");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://xxxx/api/common/getinterestlist");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                { 
                    string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    List<MobileInterest> result = new List<MobileInterest>();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MobileInterest>>(s);
                    foreach (var item in result)
                    {
                        InterestsList.Add(item.Interest);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
```

The "token" object is a JWT that is created during the Login POST method. The JWT is valid for 60 minutes.
When I run the Content Page / View Model, (MVVM), I get a 401 Unauthorized error in the HttpResponseMessage object.
If I run the very same API method with the same valid token on Postman, I have success and a return of a json object to a model.

I dont understand why the api method works on the Postman client, but fails with 401 on the iOS simulator.

I have other API calls in the Xamarin project that also work.

Where should I look?

Comment: use a tool like Wireshark (or logs on your server) to compare the two requests

Comment: Maybe check to see if `System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(token)` is returning the same value you're using in PostMan.

Comment: Cool, I just installed Wireshark. Going to see what I can see.

Comment: It's likely that there are some headers (especially language ones) that are added by default by PostMan, and it doesn't seem like you added any Header except the Authorization one. Also, there are many different kinds of authorization methods, so there's a chance that the Authorization header isn't being passed properly

Comment: Thanks Saamer, I will compare headers I might need.